# Unable to upload themes to my WordPress installation

Tags: wordpress

I am unable to upload themes to my WordPress installation via WordPress admin. I am getting the following error:

> The uploaded file could not be moved to /home/debiprasad/webapps/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/09

The permission of wp-contents directory and all sub directories are: `0755`. Some people may suggest to make it `0777`. This may work, but I don't think this is the correct solution. Because, all the folders should be have permission `0755` and this is secure. `0755` is the default and it works in other installations.

I want to know what's the reason of this error and what is the perfect and secure solution?

Comment: can you describe how you upload your theme and which format

Comment: I am talking about uploading themes via web:  Appearance → Themes → Install Themes  → Upload.

Comment: :what format folder or zip file

Comment: Of couse it's a zip file. How can you upload a folder in that page?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Apache, is your uploads folder owned by www-data?  (or whatever user apache/php run as?)

If you have access to change ownership, 0755 should work as long as the upload folder (and subdirectories within) are owned by the same "user" that the web server runs as - so in most cases, that'll be www-data.

If this doesn't work, what method do you use to install themes?  ftp, ftps or ssh2?

Comment: Ok, so I gathered from another comment you're using the dashboard uploader - so is your uploads folder owned by the web server (www-data)?  Its massively dependent on your setup, but if you created the folder yourself (as your user) and the permissions are 755, the web server may only have read/execute access, not write.

Comment: Yes, you seems to be correct. I checked directory permission, owner and group. I found that my username is the owner and group of the directory. I am not sure, whether this happens in a normal installation. Perhaps, installation by packages of hosting control panel is the culprit. I will investigate more and share here.